# How to prevent SQL search query from returning rows where columns have no value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have my search.php doing what I need...almost. It is grabbing two values from a search form (a text type value and a select type value) and storing each value in the search.php page through the code below. The one problem is that if someone leaves the text type value blank (which is the $genre value below), the code will see $genre value="" and it will return all rows for the genre column where the genre value is blank. I do not want it to return any rows where genre is blank though.

I think I need some sort of if condition, but not sure if I should apply that to the variable declaration part or the query.

```
<?php

//declaring variable 
$input = array(
"find" => $_POST['find'],
);

$genre = $input['find'][0];
$scategory = $input['find'][1];

//the sql statement 

$results = $dbh->prepare("select 

stories.SID,
stories.story_name,
stories.category,
stories.genre
FROM stories
WHERE stories.category = :cat OR stories.genre = :gen");
$results->bindParam(':cat', $scategory, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$results->bindParam(':gen', $sgenre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$results->execute();
$row = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


if ($row) {
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><b>category</b></td>';
echo '<td><b>genre</b></td>';
echo '</tr>';
foreach ($row as $all) {
echo '<tr>';
echo "<td>$all[category]</td>";
echo "<td>$all[genre]</td>";
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: You should prevent from being able to exist in a bad state from the start. If you don't want empty fields top exist, you should check that prior to inserting it. If you do want to allow empty fields, but just skip them in the queries, you should be able to use a WHERE statement to disallow grabbing records with null fields

Comment: I do need as one of the search field options a text input in case the user wants to search by a keyword they choose. If they do not enter a keyword and only select something from the select box, then there will be a blank value. But I can try where genre != null approach in my query i guess

Comment: actually that won't work b/c genre could be null for records I do want to return such as where category is selected for the search but genre is null.  Hmm. I don't know how these other multi-option search forms work I see everywhere

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show anything without a genre at all, I suggest adding a condition in your query:

```
WHERE (stories.category = :cat OR stories.genre = :gen)
AND NOT (genre = NULL OR genre = '')
```

If you are trying to only skip empty genres if no genre was specified, i suggest using a condition in the php-code:

```
if(! empty($genre)) {
  $genre = "This_aint_no_genre";
};
```

or you could change your code to

```
$genre = $input['find'][0] || "This_aint_no_genre";
```

Note: this php-code is not "clean" but practical. Use a full condition with if-else and a separate query for clean code.

Comment: I figured it out. not elegant, but I typed the query twice. For the first query where I expect no value for genre, I did if (empty($sgenre)){ query1}. Then I run the initial query if there is a value. Works great, but my get bulky if I need more input search fields later...